# Get dogtail to run on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python

I am trying to get dogtail 0.8.2 to run on my Ubuntu 12.04 to be able to automate some tests. I downloaded dogtail 0.8.2 here: https://fedorahosted.org/released/dogtail/ and used the following command to install.

```
sudo python ./setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local
```

Then I wanted to run this example found here: https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/dogtail.git/tree/examples/gedit-test-utf8-tree-api.py
but I end up in the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gedit.py", line 6, in <module>
    from dogtail import tree
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dogtail/tree.py", line 63, in <module>
    from config import config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dogtail/config.py", line 15, in <module>
    class _Config(object):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dogtail/config.py", line 117, in _Config
    'scratchDir' : '/'.join((_userTmpDir('dogtail'), '')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dogtail/config.py", line 13, in _userTmpDir
    return '-'.join(('/'.join(('/tmp', baseName)), os.getlogin()))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am quite new to Python so it might be a quite simple problem, but I don't really know how to continue from here. I will be happy for any help here.

Comment: Interesting.  Seems like `os.getlogin()` is failing with `No such file or directory`.  Could you try running your command from a different terminal application (such as xterm?).  My guess is that your terminal is not doing something with utmp that's `os.getlogin()` depends on.

Comment: Ok, that actually made a difference. Normaly I use the terminal program called "Terminator". Now that I changed, the python script starts and opens gedit. However I get stuck again with another problem but I shall see if I can fix this by myself. Thanks

Comment: I got stuck again but I posted my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828306/cant-run-dogtail-testscript